# Sharepoint 2010 List Advanced Dialog Setting only works on first Lookup field

Tags: list

I have a list with 3 lookup fields. I've gone into advanced list settings and turned Dialogs off.

When I click a link in first lookup field - the link works much like a standard a href. However when clicking a link in the other 2 lookup fields - the dialog window pops up.

I want all my links to respect the Dialog OFF, setting, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. As far as I know there is no easy solution, only complex JS hacks.